# accessing struct members in array like manner: padding in structs different than in arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, language-lawyer, unions

Suppose I have a structure comprising several members, each being of the same type. I'd like to safely access the members both by name and by an array index, so I introduced a `union` that comprises the actual `struct` and an array, which corresponds to the members of the `struct` in terms of number and type. See the following code, which illustrates how I'd like to "view" the `struct` in two different ways by using such a `union`:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename elemT>
struct productData {
    elemT color;
    elemT size;
    elemT application;
    elemT division;
};

template<typename elemT>
union productDataAsArray {
    struct productData<elemT> p;
    elemT arr[(sizeof(productData<elemT>) / sizeof(elemT))];
};

int main() {

    union productDataAsArray<int> myProduct;
    myProduct.p.color = 10;
    myProduct.p.size = 20;
    myProduct.p.application = 30;
    myProduct.p.division = 40;

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        std::cout << "elem #" << i << ":" << myProduct.arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is it safe / guaranteed by the standard to assume that the memory layout of the array corresponds to the memory layout of the `struct`, such that the two different access methods achieve the desired results for any type `elemT`?

The following `static_asserts` with several different types indicate that it should work. But is it actually guaranteed?

```
static_assert(sizeof(productData<int>)==sizeof(productDataAsArray<int>::arr), "padding/alignment inconsistency");
static_assert(sizeof(productData<char>)==sizeof(productDataAsArray<char>::arr), "padding/alignment inconsistency");
static_assert(sizeof(productData<double>)==sizeof(productDataAsArray<double>::arr), "padding/alignment inconsistency");
static_assert(sizeof(productData<char*>)==sizeof(productDataAsArray<char*>::arr), "padding/alignment inconsistency");

class alignas(16) testClass {
    int x;
    int y;
    virtual void test() {};
};

static_assert(sizeof(productData<testClass>)==sizeof(productDataAsArray<testClass>::arr), "padding/alignment inconsistency");
```

Comment: Accessing anything other than the active element of a `union` is undefined behavior.

Comment: You may add `operator[]` to your class instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your way is UB, you may instead do something like:

```
template<typename elemT>
class productData {
    elemT data[4];
public:
    const elemT& operator[](int i) const { return data[i];}
    const elemT& color() const { return data[0]; }
    const elemT& size() const { return data[1]; }
    const elemT& application() const { return data[2]; }
    const elemT& division() const { return data[3]; }

    elemT& operator[](int i) { return data[i];}
    elemT& color() { return data[0]; }
    elemT& size() { return data[1]; }
    elemT& application() { return data[2]; }
    elemT& division() { return data[3]; }
};
```

Comment: I guess `data` need not really be private as we have no invariants to protect. Anyways, nice answer; more constructive than mine. :)

Comment: I agree with @BaummitAugen, that should be the accepted answer, better than mine's and Baum's.

Comment: Thanks. While thinking about alignment, padding, and such details I forgot about checking the obvious. The structs are generated by a source code generator, so its no matter to automatically generate accessors as described in your approach. Anyway, it seems as if "viewing" given object representations from the "perspective" of another type with the same object representation always yields UB; If this is right, for what are then all the statements concerning trap representations good for?

Answer (score 4):

No need to talk about memory layout here to begin with.

You already invoke UB by reading from a `union` member other than the one last assigned to. There is no exception to this rule in standard C++.

So to be explicit: The answer to all your "Is it safe/guaranteed"-questions is "No".

Answer (score 2):

> But is it actually guaranteed?

No.

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* by accessing an inactive member of a `union`.

Answer (score 1):

As the other posts have mentioned, it is not guaranteed.

Your `static_assert`s also are not sufficient to check, as you could have padding in different places. You should explicitly verify memory location in your static asserts:

```
namespace {
const productDataAsArray<int> testObj{0};
static_assert(&testObj.p.color == &testObj.arr[0]);
static_assert(&testObj.p.size == &testObj.arr[1]);
static_assert(&testObj.p.application == &testObj.arr[2]);
static_assert(&testObj.p.division == &testObj.arr[3]);
}
```

The better solution is to index with an enum:

```
enum productDataIndexes {
  PRODUCT_COLOR = 0,
  PRODUCT_SIZE,
  PRODUCT_APPLICATION,
  PRODUCT_DIVISION,
  NUM_PRODUCT_INDEXES
};

int main() {
    ...
    myProduct[PRODUCT_COLOR] = 10;
    myProduct[PRODUCT_SIZE] = 20;
    myProduct[PRODUCT_APPLICATION] = 30;
    myProduct[PRODUCT_DIVISION] = 40;

    for (int i=0; i<NUM_PRODUCT_INDEXES; i++) {
        std::cout << "elem #" << i << ":" << myProduct[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```